# Sharepoint 2013 how to create a display template which shows 4 lines of blog

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to create a display template for a blog to show in the home using content search web part with blog post title as link , by whom, body with 2 or 3 lines and next line with how many likes and comments.

thanks

Comment: Is there a particular part of this that you have a question on?

Comment: @Graham i managed to get the number of likes but i couldn't get the Number of comments from the mapping properties

Comment: Are you using a content query, a view or a REST call to get the data?

Comment: @Graham I am using content search webpart

Comment: The content search web part out of the box won't get you what you want. Custom XSL through either the Content Query web part or through customizing the page in SP Designer will get you some control over the content, though the exact count of lines may require you to use some jQuery to truly get the look right.

Comment: But I got Number of Likes as a mapped property so I could add that easily But I want the Number of Comments as well but I couldn't.

so right now its showing only post name ,date and body and Number Of Likes. But I want to add one more line to show say 5 Likes   3 Comments

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this guide to build a Content QUERY web part on a blog and it worked.

http://erikswenson.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-content-query-for-blog.html

it does not do everything you ask, but it is quite close.

I was not able to find a similar guide on the content search web part.